# SQL Query Exclusive Read/Write to Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, locking

**SQL Server 2008:** I've got a situation here in which I wish to read from a table and write a row under certain conditions.  The problem is that I don't want another request coming it at exactly the same time and doing the same thing.  I'll try to explain here:

**Table Name:** RequestQueue

```
Columns:

RequestID, StartDate, EndDate, RequestResult

Sample Data

1, 12/4/10 1:00pm, 12/4/10 1:02pm, Success
2, 12/4/10 1:04pm, 12/4/10 1:05pm, Success
3, 12/4/10 1:00pm, NULL, NULL
```

When a page loads in my app, I want it to look at this table and if there is a request still pending like (ID #3) it will not do anything.  Otherwise, if there are no requests pending, it creates a new row with the ID and StartDate filled in.

The issue is that we could get into a situation where the page is loaded twice at almost exactly the same time.  If they happen to both read from the table before the new row is produced, then I could get two new rows in there.  I want to have some sort of query that reads from the table and if there are no requests pending, inserts the new row with the StartDate filled in.  I want that query to run all the way before another page can even read from this table so I don't get the "double row" effect.

I might need "locking" or something, I googled that but haven't found something for my exact situation.  I'm sure this could be a simple stored procedure I just need a push in the right direction here.

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  MySQL, SQL Server, etc?

Comment: What RDBMS and Version? Also do you want to block **all** concurrent reads from the table or are there some reads that are unrelated to the insert process that would best be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to block all concurrent access to the table you could just do.

```
BEGIN TRAN 

DECLARE @StartDate datetime,
        @EndDate datetime

SELECT TOP 1
            @StartDate = StartDate,
            @EndDate = EndDate
        FROM     RequestQueue WITH(TABLOCK,XLOCK)
        ORDER BY RequestID DESC


IF @EndDate IS NULL
  SELECT @StartDate AS 'StartDate'
ELSE
  INSERT INTO RequestQueue (StartDate) 
  OUTPUT INSERTED.* /* Or use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead*/
  VALUES (GETDATE())

COMMIT
```

Alternatively you could just serialise access to the `SELECT/INSERT` code inside the specific procedure without taking an exclusive table lock by using [sp_getapplock](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/application-locks-or-mutexes-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: OK, this is looking close.  So on the "If Not Exists" I need to only check the very latest row with EndDate = NULL.  (There could be other rows in the history that never completed with and EndDate)  Also, after the insert, can I select back out the new ID for that row?  Finally, how do I make it return the StartDate of the latest row in the case that the row is actually unfinished?  Thanks